# While parsing complex nested JSON file it is difficult to access/search value of the object

Tags: c++, json

Here is the json file which I'm working on --

```
{
    "statuses": [{
        "metadata": {
            "result_type": "recent",
            "iso_language_code": "ja"
        },
        "created_at": "Sun Aug 31 00:29:15 +0000 2014",
        "id": 505874924095815700,
        "id_str": "505874924095815681",
        "text": "@aym0566x \n\n名前:前田あゆみ\n第一印象:なんか怖っ！\n今の印象:とりあえずキモい。噛み合わない\n好きなところ:ぶすでキモいとこyumsparklessparkles\n思い出:んーーー、ありすぎblushheart\nLINE交換できる？:あぁ……ごめんhand\nトプ画をみて:照れますがなkissing_heartsparkles\n一言:お前は一生もんのダチsparkling_heart",
        "source": "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/download/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for iPhone",
        "truncated": false,
        "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
        "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
        "in_reply_to_user_id": 866260188,
        "in_reply_to_user_id_str": "866260188",
        "in_reply_to_screen_name": "aym0566x",
        "user": {
            "id": 1186275104,
            "id_str": "1186275104",
            "name": "AYUMI",
            "screen_name": "ayuu0123",
            "location": "",
            "description": "元野球部マネージャー❤︎…最高の夏をありがとう…❤︎",
            "url": null,
            "entities": {
                "description": {
                    "urls": []
                }
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

Using the sample code of simdjson I was able to parse whole json file but while searching for an object and it's value I wasn't able to search it just shows no such object/object value.
Please help me with the code as in how and what to do.

Here is the code

```
#include "simdjson.h"
int main(void) {
  simdjson::dom::parser parser;
  simdjson::dom::element tweets = parser.load("twitter.json");
  std::cout << "Value of ID " << tweets["statuses"]["id"] << std::endl;
}
```

Here is the output which I'm getting

```
~/simdjson-master$ c++ strt.cpp simdjson.cpp
~/simdjson-master$ ./a.out 
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'simdjson::simdjson_error'
  what():  The JSON element does not have the requested type.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

This is the output I'm expecting

```
~/simdjson-master$ c++ strt.cpp simdjson.cpp
~/simdjson-master$ ./a.out 
Value of ID 505874924095815700
```

Comment: `statuses` is an array. `tweets["statuses"][0]["id"]`

Comment: @Cid I tried this but it shows `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Comment: Then you should use a debugger to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: I would suggest to ask directly to the project maintainers, as it seems copy/paste of their example...

Comment: Found my mistake it was `std::cout << tweets["statuses"].at(0)["id"] << std::endl;`